# Javascript - Advanced JSON keypaths

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, nested

I'm looking for a library which can parse my json deeply using a keypath, i.e. find values inside an array of dictionaries.

Considering the following JSON Object:

```
{
    "root" : 
    {
        "infos" : 
        {
            "sport" : [
                        {"name" : "tennis"}, 
                        {"name" : "basket"}
                      ]
        }
    }
};
```

I would be able to do something like `var sport = json.valueForKeyPath('root.infos.sport.name')` which should return`["tennis", basket"]`.

I tried `underscore-keypath.min.js` but it can't do it.

Does someone know a library which can do that ?

Comment: `root.sport.name` or `root.infos.sport.name`?

Comment: It can be done by basic javascript, Why do you need a library for this?

Comment: @thefourtheye `root.infos.sport.name` sorry. @void how it can be done in basic JS ?

Comment: convert your json to xml [eg. with this service](http://www.utilities-online.info/xmltojson) and use xpath, xslt,... to query and process the data further. note that the resulting xml may technically be malformed (eg. not having a unique root node or lacking a xml declaration). however, these deficiencies can easily be remedied.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a little lib that can do that, you can find it on github:

https://github.com/blauharley/TemplateJS

Here is an example of what you can do with it:

```
var objs = [
    { dim: { x: 25, y:14, z: 3}, name: 'circle'},
    { dim: { x: 19, y:17, z: 8}, name: 'triangle'},
    { dim: { x: 7, y:44, z: 12}, name: 'quad'},
    { dim: { x: 13, y:63, z: 67}, name: 'circle'},
    { dim: { x: 5, y:23, z: -2}, name: 'rectangle'}
];
var templ = new TemplateJS();
// if you have got more than one value to insert separate the values with pipes (|)
var str = "<p>{name}: | <b style='color:green'>{dim}{x}px</b> | <b style='color:red'>{dim}{y}px</b> | <b style='color:yellow'>{dim}{z}px</b></p>";
templ.transformTemplate(objs,str);
```

There are two methods but **transformTemplate** suits your question more. It returns an array of strings that base on the objects given. It takes each object(out of objs-array) and puts it's property-values into a string given as second parameter. At the end **transformTemplate** returns an array of *transformed* strings.

The second method **insertTemplate** does almost the same but it is considered to be used for inserting a bunch of values into HTML-elements.

With Pipes | you separate values of objects and curly-braces are self-explaining. This lib can handle infinite object-nestings(**not arrays**) hypothetically as you can see in the TestCase done with Jasmine.

Unfortunately both methods expect an array of objects as first param so when you want to use this lib you could use it this way:

```
var source = {
  'root':
  {
    'infos':
    {
      'sport': [
        {
          'name': 'tennis'
        },
        {
          'name': 'basket'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
};
var templ = new TemplateJS();
// if you have got more than one value to insert separate the values with pipes (|)
var str = '{name}';
templ.transformTemplate(source.root.infos.sport, str); // ["tennis", "basket"]
```

Furthermore it is tested in all browsers.

Comment: It should fulfill every need. Hope you find it useful.

Comment: Can't make it work :( I'm working in a Parse Cloud Code environment, I guess not all library are allowed to be run. I have the following error `{"code":141,"error":"ReferenceError: TemplateJS is not defined\n    at modules/test.js:19:18"}` (PS : i'm a big beginner with JS)

Comment: It can't be helped. May be you'll use it somewhere else in the future,